# babel presets es2015 stage0 export deafult from

Tags: ecmascript-6, webpack, babeljs

in my `src/index.js`

```
export default from './date-picker/date-picker.js'
```

in my `.babelrc` :

```
{
  "presets": [ "es2015", "stage-0" ]
}
```

when I run npm start, I got syntax error `Unexpected token` if I remove the presets line.

```
ERROR in ./index.js
[0] Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/dev/workspace/myProject/src/index.js: Unexpected token (1:20)
[0] > 1 | export default from './date-picker/date-picker.js'
[0]     |                     ^
[0]   2 |
```

it works fine if I change stage-0 to stage-1 too.
I heard that stage-0 is used for ES7 feature but I am not using any ES7 in my code. Why it is not working when I remove the presets and where can I find more information on how Babel presets works?

Answer (score 0):

That syntax is a stage 1 proposal: https://github.com/leebyron/ecmascript-export-default-from it is not part of standard ES2015/16 and is included as part of Babel's `stage-1` preset: https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/preset-stage-1/ via https://babeljs.io/docs/plugins/transform-export-extensions/.

Comment: I always thought a stage preset includes all plugins of that or higher stages?

Comment: Yup, they do. The user says it works for them with `stage-0` or `stage-1`.

Comment: Hm, it sounded to me as if it didn't work without any presets or with `stage-0`, but it did work when changed to `stage-1`.

Comment: There is some weird wording in there, I'll wait and see what the OP says. I focused on `Why it is not working when I remove the presets`.